# Setting up complex object that contain circular references to other complex objects for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

I am unit testing a business service that depends upon other repository interfaces and service interfaces. These dependencies return complex objects that contains circular references to others complex objects. I am using MOQ to mock these dependencies and setting up their routines to return complex objects. Then I am verifying that the business service under test is returning the correct results.

Due to the complexity of these complex objects, is it a good idea to create a JSON file that represents these complex objects and deserialize it into the mock objects I am settings up? What are your thoughts?

Example of the complex object that needs to be fully populated for testing:

```
public class Foo{
    property int Id {get; set;}
    property virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}

public class Bar{
    property int Id {get; set;}
    property int BarId {get; set;}
    property virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally not a fan of the idea. You get 2 really huge benefits by creating the objects in code.

1. A compile time error if you change the object structure and miss making the same changes in your tests.
2. The possibility for a tool to automatically make cascading changes to your object definitions flow to the code in your tests (e.g. VS, Resharper).

*There are perhaps other tools that could help mitigate those things but why introduce more complexity when it isn't needed.*

In fact, unless your application is actually creating your objects in the same exact manner there could be some subtle difference in creating those object specific to the deserializer you use that helps hide defects.

Comment: That is a good point, if I make changes to a property of the class then the json would have to be updated accordingly.

Comment: The difficulty I am having with setting up mock data in the code is populating circular references. e.g., Foo contains many bars and a bar contains a foo. Have any suggestions?

Comment: How are they constructed normally? Are they lazily loaded or are there settable properties for these circular dependencies? It might help if you included a more concrete example so we're sure to be on the same page.

Comment: Lazy loaded via the entity framework 6. I'll try to include an example.

Comment: I should note however that when I am unit testing I am mocking the interface to the repository and therefore not using EF